# How can I use $(this) correctly in jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to resize text to the size of the parent box, Can someone please explain to me why this is working:

```
$('.box').css('font-size',$('.box').height());
```

and this is not working:

```
$('.box').css('font-size',$(this).height());
```

by the way I'm using jquery mobile with phonegap.

Comment: Well what does `$(this)` refer to? Try it out with `console.log($(this));`

Comment: He doesn't understand how to use `$(this)`, that's the point of this question :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That doesn't work because you're calling the `css` function of `$('.box')` and passing it the value of $(this).height(), not a reference to its self. In that case `this` is still the context of the function that holds that line of code. Try something like this, to accomplish what you want:

```
$('.box').css('font-size',function () {
   return $(this).height() + "px";
});
```

Comment: @Manolis Tagging so you'll be notified of the previous comment.

Comment: @xdumaine This is so weird, I accepted this answer yesterday and today was unticked... weird

Answer (score 5):

As you can see from [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-functionindex--value):

```
$('.box').css('font-size',function () {
   return $(this).height() + "px";
});
```

Context of the passed function is bind to the object(s) of which the `css()` method is called. That is why, `this` will be assigned to HTML element with the class `dom`.

Comment: You beat me to the punch by a few seconds, but SO strongly encourages explanations with code, to give the asker a bit of context and reasoning. See [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques).

Comment: Downvote for that? Wow... Didn't expect such a simple question need an explanation, well.

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but it may have been whoever upvoted my comment. You still had working code, after all.

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev thanks for your answer, but when I had to select a reply, since both replies where the same, I ticked the one with an explanation. Actually the code is always so much better with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

HTML:

```
 <input type="button" class="box" id="someID" value="Click this box" />
```

jQuery:

```
$('.box').click(function() {

    var test = $(this).attr('id');
    alert('Here is the ID for the element on which you clicked: ' + test);

});
```

When you trap an event, that event is associated with an element on the page. In this case, the element is the button-type input field, and the trapped event is the 'click' event.

The code inside the `click()` event function can refer to the element that triggered the event as `$(this)`.

If you wish to refer to any other element in the DOM, you must specify the element.